# How do I resize dynamically loaded image from an API?

Tags: javascript

I want to resize this image that was loaded in from an API but I don't know how:

`$('#icon').html(data.weather[0].icon)                                                                   $('#icon').html('<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png">');`

Thanks in advance

Comment: just add 'width' and 'height' as parameters in the img, as <img width="20px" height="30px">

Answer (score 0):

Reselect the image after appending.

```
$('#icon img').css('height', '50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the author is still new in JS. So if he wants to learn a little more please look at my solution.

```
document.querySelector('#icon img').height = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-write the style in your CSS and then add a class to the img tag when it's rendered.

`$('#icon').html('<img class="icon" src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png">');`

In your CSS file `.icon { height: 50px; width: 50px;}`